# How do I edit previous lines in a multiple line command in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, gnome-terminal

When entering a command which spans multiple lines in Bash, how do I edit previous lines? I'm a Linux Mint (Lisa) user using GNOME Terminal.

For example, let's say I type:

```
$ echo "foo bar
> baz
>
```

And then when I'm about to type the third line of the command, suddenly realize I want "foo" and "bar" to be on separate lines. How would I reposition my cursor between "foo" and "bar" such that I could press enter and put them on separate lines?

(It's not easy like you might think. Up arrow doesn't work, neither does Ctrl-P. So please, try it out before posting! Thanks!)

Comment: The accepted answer says there is no solution, but there is. See [below](http://superuser.com/a/895868/348062)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That, unfortunately, is up to `bash`, not to the terminal. Your options are:

1. Use semicolons instead of newlines, although even then you can't move up a screen line at a time but must use character or word motion commands.  (Oddly, `zsh` at least lets you move within a compound command when editing history, just not within the *current* command.)  Sometimes `fc` (which tosses you into your editor with the previous command) is the easiest way to handle compound commands.
2. If you are using Bash, use the following key combination:

   ```
   ctrl x e
   ```

   It will open up the command you are working on using your text editor.  Save the file and quit. (I found the command on the [Shell Hater's presentation](http://shellhaters.heroku.com/).)
   Zsh users have [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890620/unable-to-have-bash-like-c-x-e-in-zsh).

Comment: The bash man page explains how to change which editor is used: edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e) - Invoke  an  editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands.  Bash attempts to invoke $VISUAL, $EDITOR, and emacs as the editor, in that order.

Comment: There is a solution, without opening the editor.

Comment: Technically its not up to bash - but to the "readline" library that bash uses to get inputs.

Answer (score 21):

The solution is to never enter a command until the multi-line is right, just type:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>
when you want to go to the next line. <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to go back a word.

[image: solution]

credit to @rici's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/895631/348062)

Comment: What is the Meta button?

Comment: @Jas the `Meta` Button is pressing `Alt` and the keystrokes (simultaneously) or pressing `Escape` then the keystroke (alterlatively)

Answer (score 12):

Funnily enough, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is what you are looking for.

when you are on

```
$ echo "foo bar
> baz
>
```

just press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (edited command line will suspend) and press <kbd>Up</kbd> (previous-history). Your prompt will be: (note the absence of >)

```
$ echo "foo bar
baz
```

Now you can move around with <kbd>Left</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> even through line jumps.

There is only one quirk, you must be on the last character to add another line, so move around to edit existing lines (go to start with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>) an press <kbd>Enter</kbd>  if that's enough or goto end (<kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>) to add more lines with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Another drawback is that <kbd>Ctrl+_</kbd> (undo) only restores changes from last <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

Answer (score -4):

Copy the commands and paste them in notepad then format it from there. After that you can copy your commands back to the terminal.