# Bind a key to newline in Bash, without submitting command

Tags: bash, readline

I want to press <kbd>M-j</kbd> and have readline place my cursor on the next line without entering a command. Thus I should be able to go back a character onto the prev. line. This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/409155/348062) states that it cannot be done. I think it's wrong.

You can kill the newline character, and yank it. This achieves what I want to do. However I just can't create the binding.

To test this out type: `echo <<EOF`<kbd>RETURN</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-p</kbd><kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>

Now you should be on a newline, type <kbd>C-y</kbd>. It does what I want! But what character is this? What binding works in an inputrc file?

**EDIT:** It turns out the character is a line-feed. Still not sure how to bind it.

Comment: You can type a newline as C-v C-j, which is mostly useful for breaking lines up while line editing. The linked question is referring to up and down cursor motions in a multi-line line edit. I'm not sure that either of those are what you want to do.

Comment: I added some to clarify, I want to be on the next line and able to go back.

Comment: On my system, @rici's shortcuts seem to achieve what you're asking for. What happens on yours?

Comment: That is the correct behavior, The following binding works `"\ej": "\C-v\C-j"` based on how my terminal interprets meta. Please post an answer for me to accept @rici

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can type a newline character without having the line accepted by using readline's "quoted-insert", usually bound to <kbd>C-v</kbd>, followed by the newline character <kbd>C-j</kbd>.

"quoted-insert" is also useful for typing a tab character without invoking tab completion (<kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>C-i</kbd>).

Comment: Wow this is really useful, anyway to make this automatic when I use `\\` to escape the newline when creating a multiline command?

Comment: @cmcdragonkai: not that I know of but you could bind some key sequence to `\\\C-j`.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
bind '"\C-j": "\C-v\C-j"'
```